# minimist failing in testcafe

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, minimist

I am using minimist to run different environment for my TestSuite using test cafe however i am facing some issues

I have the following example.ts file

```
import * as minimist from 'minimist';

const args = minimist(process.argv.slice(2))
const environment = args.env

fixture('example')
 .page("https://example.com")

test('check environment', async t => {
  console.log('Environment:', environment);

   if(environment =='Test')
   {
    console.log('Environment:', environment);

   }

   
   else if(environment=='Stage')
   {
    console.log('Environment:', environment);
    
   }
});
```

and the below command line  package.json

```
"minitest":"testcafe chrome:headless scripts/example.ts --env=Test"
```

when I run "npm run minitest" I get the below error, what am I doing wrong?

```
error: unknown option '--env=Test'
npm ERR! code 1
```

Comment: We are aware of this issue. You can track our progress here: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6426.

Comment: Is this fixed as a part of https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/pull/6429?

Comment: Yes, of course.